# Slow reactions from my application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, devexpress, scheduler

In my applicattion I use the scheduler control from devexpress this scheduler use for the appointments and resources `DataSource` two `DataTables` that I populate with data from my mssql server data base, to show the info the scheduler control is refreshing each 30 seconds so I update the `DataSource` each 30 seconds. At first the application reactions are really fast but while more time the application is running more slow it gets let say at 20 minutes running a simple thing like select one time cell takes 4 seconds to set the focus on that time cell.

Any suggestion of how to solve this problem?

Comment: The first step in a solution would be to provide some details about what is going on. Start with some code so we know what you are really doing here.

Comment: Visual Studio comes with a number of Profilers and Analytics to help show you where the code is sloppy, leaking, wasteful and hard to maintain